# make div scroll infinitely with option for both directions

Tags: jquery, carousel, infinite-scroll

I am using the plugin Smooth Div Scroll's (http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/) Quick Demo. Everything works well except one thing: making it loop infinitely; for both sides.

I've tried and tried and tried. No luck yet.

Hoping someone can help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Roll your own, it's less than 200 lines of css transitions and js code .

Comment: not that advanced though although I'm able to modify someone else's code to suit the required action. not this one though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is given the code the properly. Perhaps you have missed some thing:

```
manualContinuousScrolling: true,
```

Use this option also with code.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav. It didn't work though. Probably because I have <div> enclosing each image, which is necessary